# Unable to show data in Gridview in Android ! please help me out

Tags: android, database, gridview, cursor

I am entering some values in to my SQLlite database and then retrieving them in a gridview.I am getting a Error "column'_id'" does not exist.but I have not used any _id named column in the database. How can I make it work?? I think theres some problem with SimpleCursor Adapter .

```
    GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    try
    {
        db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("record.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
          db1.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stu(ID INTEGER primary Key,NAME VARCHAR foriegn key,age VARCHAR);");
         db1.execSQL("INSERT INTO stu VALUES (1,'mona','123');");

    Cursor c = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM stu", null);
    if(c!= null){
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String[] cols = new String[]{c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"))};
            int[]   views = new int[]   {R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2};

                 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        c, cols, views);
                    gv.setAdapter(adapter);

               }while(c.moveToNext());}

    }} catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"errord"+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) (which SimpleCursorAdapter extends) states:

```
The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.
```

Comment: sorry if it sounds silly but I am new to android , does I have to include a column named _id in my database ?

Comment: I have done this now
Cursor c = db1.rawQuery("SELECT ID as _id,NAME,age FROM stu", null);
but another error pops up .. how to do this ??

Comment: Yes, your schema for your table must include a column labeled _id.  Change db1.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stu(ID INTEGER primary Key,NAME VARCHAR foriegn key,age VARCHAR);"); to

db1.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stu(_id INTEGER primary Key,NAME VARCHAR foriegn key,age VARCHAR);");

Comment: Thanks for your reply but theres still some error popping up, as u instructed I have changed the value of "ID" as _id and in the line c.getColumnIndex("ID"), I have changed it to c.getColumnIndex("_id").
The error I still get is 
"get field slot from row 0 col-1 failed"

Comment: If possible Can you please post the code , which you think will most probably work ? It will be of great  help to me as Gridview is an important part of my project. Please Sir.